# how to connect to ad-hoc network in android emulator in android4.0 platform?

Tags: android, wifi, emulation

i want to develop android application in which runs in my pc and connects to different android devices through wify and communicate with them,so i am trying to connect an ad-hoc network through my android phone.i found that this is supported only in android 4.0.so i want to test this in emulator,how can i connect emulator in a ad-hoc wifi network,if it is possible,plese help me to conncect emulator to a ad-hoc network created by my Laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, my guess is that it's not.

It's not listed as a Property you can set when you create a new emulator. Neither is it listed in the Emulator Control under DDMS.

Besides, even if it were in there (which it's not), you'd probably still need two different computers to simulate the connection (not just one pretending to be connecting to itself).